# How to use a MenuButton (Gtkmm)

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I am trying to use a `MenuButton` but it does not work.

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
   Glib::RefPtr< Gtk::Application >  app = Gtk::Application::create( "App1" );
   Gtk::Window window;

   Gtk::MenuButton menuButton;
   menuButton.set_label("menu button");
   Gtk::Menu menu;
   Gtk::Label label1("label1");
   Gtk::Label label2("label2");
   Gtk::MenuItem item1(label1);
   Gtk::MenuItem item2(label2);
   menu.append(item1);
   menu.append(item2);
   menuButton.set_popup(menu);

   window.add(menuButton);
   window.show_all();
   return app->run(window);
}
```

It isn't working. Calling `set_menu()` instead of `set_popup()` doesn't work either.
The result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is correct! You only need a call to `menu.show_all()`:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv)
{
   Glib::RefPtr< Gtk::Application >  app = Gtk::Application::create( "App1" );
   Gtk::Window window;

   Gtk::MenuButton menuButton;
   menuButton.set_label("menu button");
   Gtk::Menu menu;
   Gtk::Label label1("label1");
   Gtk::Label label2("label2");
   Gtk::MenuItem item1(label1);
   Gtk::MenuItem item2(label2);
   menu.append(item1);
   menu.append(item2);
   menu.show_all();
   menuButton.set_popup(menu);

   window.add(menuButton);
   window.show_all();
   return app->run(window);
}
```